# swift- use of undeclared type 'firebase' in ios

Tags: ios, swift

i have install pods of firebase and import framework as well and have done everything possible.. but still i get this use of undeclare 'firebase' error.
    import UIKit
    import JSQMessagesViewController
    import Firebase

```
class ChatViewController: JSQMessagesViewController  {
    var ref: Firebase
    @IBOutlet weak var blackBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var TypeTxt: UITextField!
    var messages = [JSQMessage]()
    var outgoingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage!
    var incomingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      ref = Firebase(url: "https://candleheart-6bee6.firebaseio.com/")
//    var ref = Firebase(url:"https://fir-example-fea13.firebaseio.com/names")
//    ref.setValue(["name":"mamta"])
//           title = "ChatChat"
        setupBubbles()
        collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSizeZero
        collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = CGSizeZero
       // messageRef = rootRef.childByAppendingPath("messages")
        TypeTxt.layer.cornerRadius = 22.0
        TypeTxt.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        TypeTxt.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
         TypeTxt.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you build and clean the project?

After adding a framework through CocoaPods, in most conditions you are supposed to clean and build the project right away.

That should take care of adding/building the new framework to your app and make it active for use

Also, please note that another copy of your project will be created upon addition with pods, called something like 'yourProjectName.xcworkspace' (You can find it in your directory). It will have a light blue color thumbnail. After adding your pods, you must start using that copy of your project instead of the normal project.

// Note : Generally with CocoaPods, when you add a pod to your Podfile, you just need to save the Podfile and type 'podinstall' in your terminal. Make sure to get to your project directory before that. That will import the frameworks automatically. However, you do need to write import statement in your file to use it obviously

You do not need to import framework explicitly (if using Cocoa Pods)

Comment: @aarti Did you drag framework files to your project? Just curious

Comment: You aren't supposed to drag any files to project. Just mention the pod in podfile and use pod install in your terminal. And nothing else. Also clean and build right after.

Comment: firstly i have install pods after that i drag firebase framework in app

Comment: Don't drag anything. Follow my steps. First delete any firebase files you dragged from outside. (also remove binaries and frameworks related to firebase.)

Next add pod name in pod file. And then do pod install.

Comment: Once you do pod install, then you should clean and build project, it will directly bring all files to project. Read the answer carefully, it has everything in it

Comment: i cant chat there. can you please rply  here

Comment: It is very straight forward: refer to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIbdT1ADNpE